# $\frac{1}{4}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n3^n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does $\frac{1}{4}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n3^n$ when expressed as a series?

To see if the series converges to $\frac{1}{4}$, I have to evaluate the series. I feel like this equation is wrong, since this is an alternating series, and using a test we see that $3^n$ is always growing, which means it diverges. That means $\frac{1}{4}$ is impossible to get as a number. Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: Isn't the original question asks for $3^{-n}$?

Comment: @DávidLaczkó wut I didn't make a typo so it's asking for $(-1)^n3^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometric series is divergent, because the terms are getting larger and larger.
A geometric series only converges if $|r| < 1$.

In this case $r = -3$, making it an alternating series as well, but it is still divergent considered that way because the terms don't go to zero.

Comment: It's an alternating series.

Comment: Yes I know.  I expanded to make that clearer, why on earth am I getting 3 downvotes for a correct answer?

Comment: No, it is divergent.  The terms oscillate outward towards both $-\infty$ and $\infty$.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor so it is divergent, meaning that it is not $\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: Correct, it is not $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Hi Robert, I must apologize to you on multiple counts. First, the above question was debatably a problem statement question, because the user did not provide any more than an informal explanation. However, I had second thoughts and realized that the attempt given was correct enough, although not entirely precise. But the question is closed : we are still trying to hold out for higher standards. Sometimes, when bad questions are answered we downvote the answers , because these are the encouraging factors behind these questions. I remove my downvote to your answer.

Comment: But this question is not bad, it may be closable but there is some debate around that. I do not wish that you be the victim of such a debate. However, in the future do be careful and try to answer questions which are clear and helpful to you and where you feel the OP has done a good amount of work and research prior to posting. I appreciate your answer, which also does more than the other answer in terms of classifying the series and stating the answer clearly. I cannot give you a +1 here since the question has been closed, but I will find one of your good answers and give you a +1 there.

Comment: If I had to give an example : please don't find yourself trying to answer [this kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4085106/how-to-solve-this-indefinite-integral-by-hand-int-sqrt1-cos2-x-dx) of a question. I don't mind if you have answered such questions in your history on the site : why, I did as well. The important thing is to recognize and change : and that hasn't happened with a lot of the so-called "high-rep users" on the site. I hope this example was illustrative.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=0}^m(-3)^m=\dfrac{1-(-3)^{m+1}}{1-(-3)}$$

Now $\lim_{m\to\infty}(-3)^{m+1}=?$

Comment: So you're saying that it diverges? Then am I correct to say that it is not equal to $\frac{1}{4}$?